# Youtube videos not playing in Firefox

Tags: updates, youtube

Since my latest update on Ubuntu, I cannot play any youtube videos anymore. The videos are just black with a white circle with a `F' inside in the middle. On other websites the videos do work. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have FlashBlock extension.Disable it.